# converting alphanumeric string to byte in java?

Tags: java, string, byte, alphanumeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a hex string to a byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467005/convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-in-java)

Here, I need to convert alphanumeric String  to byte value ,for example:

**String str ="1b"** to byte value.I tried by using `getbytes`,`(Byte.valueOf(str))`, (`Byte.parseByte(str))`.

All the commands showed an exception called

```
  java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

help please

Comment: Are you expecting to get a value of 27, i.e. 0x1b?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're always going to have a 2-character string representing a hex value, you just want:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(text, 16);
```

You need to specify the 16 so that it knows to treat it as hex.

Comment: what if it is a 3-character string?

Comment: @user1939336: Then it doesn't represent a single byte in hex, does it?

Comment: I need to convert alphanumeric string of 3-character to a byte ,then what i have to do for that?

Comment: @user1939336: It's impossible to answer that without knowing what value you'd want. What byte value should "XYZ" give? Once you've decided the behaviour you want, the implementation should be easy - but until you've decided that, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 2):

i hope this  may help you

```
public class TestByte
{    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

            String example = "example100";
            byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();

            System.out.println("Text : " + example);
            System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using

> Byte.parseByte("0x0b", 16);
>   16:radix