# Read file as hexadecimal then write it again from hex string

Tags: java

how do I read any file like images , videos , text Files .... etc

as an hex `String` then write these `String` again in other place but with ability to open file as original

I'm looking for a code ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a filecopy program you are asking?

Comment: you don't read as hex string. You always read bytes, but then you may convert the byte stream to a hex-string for whatever purpose.

Comment: @vembutech no it doesn't a copy program it's for another purpose

Comment: @cello reading as byte then convert it to hex or whatever you do but I'm ask If I have an hex string that represent a file is there any way to write this file again and open it ???

Comment: @BlackRoot: convert the hex string back to a byte stream and write that to a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467005/convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-in-java

Comment: @cello I have a file that contains "test one test" string after reading file and get hex string and convert hex to byte and write it using this code `RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\file.txt", "rw");
file.write(bytes);
file.close();` I've got dummy charecters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read File into Array of bytes and convert it to Hex**

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : bytes) {
                result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
            }
 result.toString();
```

**Make any modification to hex then save it again using this method**

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

**This Method return an Array of `byte` so you can write these bytes using this code**

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile([Any file Name with extention], "rw");

file.write(bytes);

file.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

use the format() method.

Read your file as bytes and then convert it to bytes.

```
String.format("%02x", byteFromFile);
```

Iterate it until all bytes are read and then add it to a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder hexbyteString;

for(byte myfile : filebyte) {
        hexbyteString.append(String.format("%02x", myfile));
    }
    return hexbyteString.toString();
```

Comment: I'm not asking for read file as an Hexadecimal I'm asking for convert hex string back to original file and open it

Comment: convert the hex String to a byte array and then write it into a file.